# unable to open database file in sqlite (using finisar.sqlite)

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using sqlite database with **sqlite.net dll** in my application.
Namespace is **Finisar.sqlite**
I have problem while inserting entries in to database using transaction, It throws exception at open connection as "unable to open database file".

I google it but solutions are like change connection string. if i follow that process then finisar gives me exception as invalid params.

```
SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(f_strConnStr);

db.Open();

**Valid parameters are:** 

Data Source=<database file>  (required)

Version=<version of SQLite (2 or 3)>            (default: 2)

New=True|False                  (default: False)

Compress=True|False                 (default: False)

UTF8Encoding=True|False             (default: False)

UTF16Encoding=True|False            (default: False)

Cache Size=<N>                  (default: 2000)

Synchronous=Full|Normal|Off             (default: Normal)

DateTimeFormat=ISO8601|Ticks|CurrentCulture     (default: ISO8601)

Compatibility=[old-date-format][,old-binary-format] (default: None)
```

**I tried solution like pooling connection string, journal mode = off etc but nothing works for me. even i can not create file which is password protected due to invalid parameter.**

I can not add other than this parameters.
If anyone having solution regarding this issue please help us.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the ***exact*** exception text?

Comment: "unable to open database file" this is what i get from Exception.message
If you need more info i will give you

Comment: Can you open it in another program which can open SQLite Databases? Like the Firefox plugin.

Comment: no i am applying lock(){ Insert statements} on it. only my application using that file.
But i have two application 1st is windows service and 
2nd is Windows application.
How will i know weather file is using in another application.
and i can open it in sqliteExpert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So a number of things could be going wrong here:

1. The folder the SQLite database is in, you don't have **Write** permissions to.
2. The database is already open by another `SQLiteConnection`.
3. The connection string is wrong. I think this one is unlikely because it's clearly a variable you're pulling the connection string from and I have to believe other times you wanted data you used the same string.

To remedy **#2** you should **always** access your data like this:

```
using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(f_strConnStr))
{
    c.Open();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Connection String is
Data Source= FilePath;Version=3;New=false;Compress=True;

Comment: @Pratik, as I stated in #3, I doubt the connection string is your problem. And it's not that likely you **don't** have **Write** permissions. The most likely suspect is an `SQLiteConnection` object that wasn't disposed of properly because you didn't use it properly. Make sure you're connecting (as I showed you) and doing your work inside the `using` statement at *all times.*

Comment: Is there any way to know weather sqlite connection is already open using another thread or process?

Comment: @Pratik, yeah, with a memory profiler. You'd be able to see an undisposed object.

Comment: ok thanks for that.
and i am using this code:
if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    //connection.Dispose();
                }
In finally block.

Comment: @Pratik, don't do that. Just create the `SQLiteConnection` in the `using` like I showed you and the `Close` and `Dispose` will happen **automatically** when you exit the scope of the `using`.

Comment: Ok no problem i will check it and let you know immediately.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34058/discussion-between-pratik-and-michael-perrenoud)